# How do I use Method Overloading in Laravel Controller?

Tags: php, laravel, oop, overloading

I am trying to use method overloading feature in my laravel controller class. here is my methods

```
  # Load Customer Balance View
  public function createBalance()
  {
    return view('customer.balance');
  }

  # Load Customer Balance View
  public function createBalance($CustomerID)
  {
    // show balance of the the defined customer
  }
```

Here is my route -

```
    // customer balance
    Route::get('Customer/Balance', 'CustomerController@createBalance');

    Route::get('Customer/Balance/{ID}', 'CustomerController@createBalance');
```

But it shows the error -

```
FatalErrorException in CustomerController.php line 45:
Cannot redeclare App\Http\Controllers\CustomerController::createBalance()
```

Any solution please ?

Comment: You can't. PHP isn't built that way.

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/165467/why-php-doesnt-support-function-overloading

Comment: Isn't php OOP language ? Its a feature of OOP language to have method overloading feature.

Comment: Not all OOP languages. The link I provided explains how PHP implements it, and how to implement what you want to do.

Comment: You could make the route param optional, that wouldn't exactly be what you want, but it'd solve this problem. (https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#parameters-optional-parameters)

Comment: In the link you provided , the functions argument is counted and based on the number of argument I have to use condition to do my task. This is not the proper method overloading, however it did help me done my task. Thank you. @aynber

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider use default parameters:

```
  public function createBalance($CustomerID=null)
  {
    if ($CustomerID==null)
      return view('customer.balance');
    else
      // show balance of the the defined customer
  }
```

And change your route to:

```
Route::get('Customer/Balance/{CustomerID?}', 'CustomerController@createBalance');
```

Adding a **"?"** after the argument, Laravel understands you're passing an optional parameter.

Comment: Thanks Luiz :). Though I have already did my task counting the arguments of the functions, but  I had to write two route calls . Following you, it saved me one line.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have different method names. This doesn't follow basic routing conventions either. The first createBalance method should probably be the index method.

Answer (score 1):

I think `createBalance()` method alredy exist in your `CustomerController` so you should create new method or different name method and also change in route file with new method name.